# SQLite AFTER UPDATE Trigger to Rename Same File Names

Tags: sqlite, triggers, sql-update

I'm storing some file Informations in DB, And generating file names by sql.

I'm UPDATING ALL ROWS with :

```
UPDATE contacts_New SET PhotoName=PersonName||'_'|| Date
```

The Question is, I want to rename duplicates like :

```
    Person1_Date -> Person1_Date
    ........
    Person2_Date -> Person2_Date
    Person2_Date -> Person2_Date-2
    Person2_Date -> Person2_Date-3
    Person2_Date -> Person2_Date-4
    ........
    Person10_Date -> Person10_Date
```

I try to do it with UPDATE TRIGGER:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ReNamePhotoNames UPDATE OF PhotoName ON contacts_New for each row
  BEGIN
    UPDATE contacts_New SET PhotoName=PhotoName || '-' || (SELECT count(*)+1 from contacts_New where PhotoName=new.PhotoName) WHERE (PhotoName=new.PhotoName);
  END;
```

Result:

```
Person1_Date -> Person1_Date
........
Person2_Date -> Person2_Date
Person2_Date -> Person2_Date-2
Person2_Date -> Person2_Date-2
Person2_Date -> Person2_Date-2
........
Person10_Date -> Person10_Date
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED THE PROBLEM:

```
            DROP TRIGGER IF exists ReNamePhotoNames;
            CREATE TRIGGER ReNamePhotoNames AFTER UPDATE OF PhotoName ON contacts_New for each row
              BEGIN
                UPDATE contacts_New SET PhotoName =
                    new.PhotoName || 
                    CASE WHEN 
                        (SELECT count(*) from contacts_New where (PhotoName LIKE new.PhotoName ||'%')) > 1 
                    THEN 
                        (SELECT count(*) from contacts_New where (PhotoName LIKE new.PhotoName ||'%')) 
                    ELSE '' END || '.jpg'
                WHERE ((PhotoName LIKE new.PhotoName) AND (IFNULL(PhotoCreated,'') IS NOT ''));
              END;
```